# Is it possible to use mootools and jQuery both together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have to use mootools and jquery files together. But there is a conflict occurs while using both together. Is there any solution to avoid this conflict?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Theoretically yes, though when I tried it produced quite a bit of grief.

Comment: one solution is to actually just use one of them. toolkits these days are pretty matched in speed and spec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to include this code just after you include your jQuery and before you include Mootools.

```
<script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

You'll then want to find/replace all jQuery `$` references with `j$`, preferably using the automated tool found in most code editors.

---

You also have another option, a closure. It would look something like this, if I remember correctly:

```
(function($) {
  //jQuery stuff
})(jQuery);
```

You'll want to move all your existing code inside this function. It scopes the `$` variable so you can do business with jQuery as usual within the closure, then use Mootools outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

**It is** (possible to use both libraries together).

From the official jQuery site on how to make it work with other libraries:
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries