# Mootools: wait until all ajax requests are done

Tags: ajax, mootools

This is very similar to [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done), except that I want to know the best practice of doing that in Mootools.

Comment: Mootools is compatible with jQuery, so you should be able to do exactly the same thing as described in the post you linked.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100057/is-it-possible-to-use-mootools-and-jquery-both-together

Comment: Does Mootools itself provide any methods for this?

Comment: I don't see one in the documentation, no.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you can wrap request in a 3rd party promises/flow api but it's not out of the box. Request.Queue is a halfway solution.

Answer (score 2):

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.Queue

> In addition to these events there is an onEnd event that is fired when all the requests have finished.

I'm going to extend the example from the documentation:

```
var myRequests = {
    r1: new Request({
        url: '/foo1.php', data: { foo1: 'bar1'},
        onComplete: function(text, xml){
            console.log('myRequests.r1: ', text, xml);
        }
    }),
    r2: new Request({
        url: '/foo2.php', data: { foo2: 'bar2'},
        onComplete: function(text, xml){
            console.log('myRequests.r2: ', text, xml);
        }
    })
};
var myQueue = new Request.Queue({
    requests: myRequests,
    concurrent: myRequests.length,
    onEnd: function() {
        console.log('Everything is done!');
    },
    onComplete: function(name, instance, text, xml){
        console.log('queue: ' + name + ' response: ', text, xml);
    }
});

myQueue.send();
```