# Jquery in Joomla 3.4

Tags: jquery, joomla3.4

Here is the website: http://backup2015.a-head.at/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=6

I am using a Jquery script but where should the following script be attached to as Joomla offers only the opportunity to add CSV/ JS??

I added the the script into the `media/system/js` directory, further in the `templates/js`  and `RSForm/js` directory as it is a **range2dslider.js** script.

When I execute the link above then I can see in the head that the scripts are running. **2drangeslider.js** runs. However, it is not possible to enable the mousemove of the button on the x Axis, meaning I can't move the button on the x-axis.

I suppose because the jquery is not attached to the slider.

Also below is a screenshot of the element/range slider in purple.

Image of the relevant element slider

[image]

Answer (score -2):

mootools-more-1.4-full.js - 404 Not Found

Comment: Thx - Just for understanding - why is mootools-more-1.4-full.js needed for a jquery? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100057/is-it-possible-to-use-mootools-and-jquery-both-together